# How do I get over this hip flexor strain?

Tags: injury, pain, hip

While doing squats, I strained my hip flexor in my right leg. This was two weeks ago. I foolishly did a lot of stretching the next few days (especially the lunge stretch), which actually inflammed my hip flexor even more. I stopped stretching, but now my hip flexor is more swollen and it hurts to sit in a chair. I've been icing my hip for the last few days. However, I can still walk lightly without too much discomfort.

I can't see physical therapist for a month, because of financial and scheduling reasons. What can I do in the meantime to speed up recovery?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are asking us to provide a course of treatment which is not really on topic for the site. Considering the age of the question, I hope that you did get in to see a PT and that the outcome was what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear that you are (or were, 15 months ago) in pain.  [Anti-inflammatory medications](http://startingstrength.com/article/inflammation_sullivan) (for example, NSAIDS) might reduce pain and inflammation.  As you may know, these are relatively inexpensive and available without restriction, at least in the U.S.A.

You may find some relief, and accelerate the healing process, by returning to your squats, **with emphasis on "perfect" form**, and temporarily using lower weights.  For example, if you had been squatting 100kg for three sets of five, then squat 50kg for three sets of eight during your first workout.

It is possible that the cause of the pain is not a hip flexor strain, but instead an impingement of soft tissue between your anterior inferior iliac spine (AIIS) and your femur.  To avoid this, be sure to angle your toes approximately 30 degrees outward before you squat, and shove your knees outward (laterally) over your feet as you squat.